# How do you repair defenses in Tiny Heroes?

Tags: ios, tiny-heroes

In Tiny Heroes on the iPhone, there is an achievement that you can get for repairing 200 defenses.  However, I don't see any way to repair defenses.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, it is an actual Defense that you use, not a general game mechanic that you need to use. It unlocks in the second campaign.

From a [thread on Touch Arcade](http://forums.toucharcade.com/showthread.php?p=1921896):

> Yeah, we're going to reword the description of the
>   "Repair-Man-Man-Man" Achievement to indicate that it's an actual
>   Defense you use, and not a general gameplay mechanic that players
>   haven't discovered.

Comment: I confirm that it's another defense that you unlock. The icon for it the same as the achievement's.